# get total attendance from time_sheet

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I have been trying to override ( def get_worked_day_lines ) to get total attendance from time_sheet_sheet.sheet for each employee so I can make a payslip for him based on total_attendance.

```
class hr_payslip(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'hr.payslip'


_columns = {

}


def get_worked_day_lines(self, cr, uid, ids, employee_id, date_to, context=None):
    
            res = []
    working_days = self.pool.get('hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet')
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context = context):
        search_sheet = working_days.search(cr, uid, [('state','=','draft')])
        for rec in working_days.browse(cr, uid, search_sheet, context=None):

            attendances = {
             'name': _("Normal Working Days paid at 100%"),
             'sequence': 1,
             'code': 'WORK100',
             'number_of_days': 0.0,
             'number_of_hours': 0.0,
             #'contract_id': ,
        }
            if rec.day == record.numero :

                attendances['code'] = rec.day
            leaves = {}
            leaves = [value for key,value in leaves.items()]
            res += [attendances] + leaves
    return res
```

ps: when I put
`search_sheet = working_days.search(cr, uid,[('state','=','draft')])`
I will be able to get total_attendance from all draft time sheets

[output for search_sheet = working_days.search(cr, uid,[('state','=','draft')])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d2Jg.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting code, try to simplify it to a [MCVE] . Your question seems simple, but anyone trying to help you is going to have to spend several minutes reading through your code to find the relevant parts. Since you already know your code and how it works, you can pull out the most important stuff and save the people who want to help you's time.

Comment: thank you, I've tried to make my code as simple as possible so that anyone who knows a little bit python and odoo can understand it... all I do here is browsing and searching but I can't get results.....

Comment: The code may be simple, but your problem isn't reproducible unless you provide sample data. It also isn't clear what your problem is -- what does the output to this function look like now, and how do you want it to look instead?

Comment: that's what I said : ps: when I put `search_sheet = working_days.search(cr, uid,[('state','=','draft')])` I will be able to get total_attendance from all draft time sheets
but when I use `search_sheet = working_days.search(cr, uid,[('employee_id','=',employee_id)])` nothing happens, no output

Comment: @FridyHola you will get more info on my custom addon for timesheet based payroll, and check the codes for getting total attendance.

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/payroll_timesheet/

Comment: @Burmesepythis thank you for your help. but your module is in odoo 10 and i'm using version 7... also I'm new with odoo

Comment: @FridyHola but you can adapt the code, I didnt event touched openerp 7 and below versions and not interested in so far. But still wonder people using the old versions !

Answer (score 0):

I actually work on OpenERP v7, so I know what is going on here. If you aren't getting anything with the [('employee_id','=',employee_id)] search criteria, then its because the value of the employee_id argument, doesn't equal any employee_id in the database.

What you should do is check the value of the employee_id that is passed in as an argument to the function. If the value is an integer, then check if that id exists in the database. You should see data if that id exists on that table.  If the value of employee_id is False or None, then you will not get any data back from the search()